# Error when adding widget : Unfortunately, "MyApp" has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I made an app with a widget, and when I add or remove the widget on my phone, or restart my phone with the widget on my homescreen, it comes up with an error "Unfortunate, Clock has stopped." (Clock is the name of my app.) The widget works fine, but I need to get rid of the error message. Eclipse didn't say that there was any problem.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tzemachzr.clock"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tzemachzr.clock.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.tzemachzr.clock.ClockWidgetProvider">
<intent-filter>
  <action
     android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
  android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
  android:resource="@xml/clock_appwidget" />
</receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Widget Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalogClock xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</AnalogClock>
```

App Widget Provider (res-xml-clock_appwidget.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="140dp"
android:minWidth="140dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/clock_appwidget_layout" android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical">

</appwidget-provider>
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.tzemachzr.clock.ClockWidgetProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tzemachzr.clock.ClockWidgetProvider
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2383)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tzemachzr.clock.ClockWidgetProvider
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2378)
08-12 15:56:27.433 E/AndroidRuntime( 5480):     ... 10 more
08-12 15:56:27.453 D/Launcher.Model( 1729): DbDebug    Add item (null) to db, id: 66 (-100, 2, 0, 2)
08-12 15:56:27.453 E/EmbeddedLogger( 1598): App crashed! Process: com.tzemachzr.clock
08-12 15:56:27.453 E/EmbeddedLogger( 1598): App crashed! Package: com.tzemachzr.clock v1 (1.0)
08-12 15:56:27.463 E/EmbeddedLogger( 1598): Application Label: Clock
08-12 15:56:27.513
```

Answer (score 1):

You got a ClassNotFoundException, that means that android doesnt find the class

> com.tzemachzr.clock.ClockWidgetProvider

Edit:

Okay, it seems that the basics arent clear.

You need a class, named ClockidgetProvider.
This class extends AppWidgetProvider and uses the meta data, stored in your clock_appwidget.xml.

So, when you declare a receiver in your Android manifest, android creates a receiver, which consists of your AppWidgetProvider class and your meta data.

See example:

```
package com.tzemachzr.clock;

 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
 import android.content.Context;

 public class ClockWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

}
```

Your meta data xml file is correct.
Add this class and see ,whether is solves your problem or not.

PS: you can set flags, by simply call:

```
System.out.println("hello");
```

This will print "hello" in your Logcat!

Comment: Sorry, I know that its better to use comments instead, but this is the only way, to collect reputations until I can comment...   @user3931926 : yes, this is the same, in your case the appwidgetprovider is the class "ClockWidgetProvider"

Comment: When did your App crashs? Try to find the exact code line using logcat flags. Set up a flag after every line in your ClockWidgetProvider class and count the logcat outputs til it crashs and please post your ClockWidgetProvider Class!

Comment: I have the text of the widget provider xml, but I'm not so sure what you mean by the class and where it's located.

Comment: And I'm not sure how to put in flags

Comment: @LunationStudios Thanks, but where exactly do I all that text that you posted inside the receiver? In the intent filter, before it, after it etc?